# Open terminal in nautilus

Tags: nautilus, command-line

Is there any stable open terminal plugin for nautilus?

Comment: u mean a plugin that opens a terminal in that folder, right?

Comment: Yeah ,without using cd command

Comment: i have a script. yoneed to put it in the my scripts folder(right click in nautilus--->scripts---->scripts folder.) will that do?

Comment: Yeah ,post it as answer

Comment: That other duplicate  question is 6 months newer than this question - does that matter? Or should this one be the duplicate, because the other one has more answers & votes, or some other reason?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I use [nautilus-open-terminal](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/nautilus-open-terminal) [image: Install nautilus-open-terminal] (click to install) from the ubuntu repos (no need to add a ppa!). This adds a "open in terminal" item to the right-click  menu in nautilus.

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-open-terminal
```

Afterwards you have to restart nautilus by logging out then back in, or this command:

```
nautilus -q && nautilus &
```

Answer (score 2):

You really shouldn't be crashing when using the `Open in Terminal` extension. There was an issue in 11.10 between it & ubuntuone libs  but it was resolved. Are you fully updated?

Anyway this ppa has an excellent `Open Terminal Here`, it's a nautilus python extension & will work just fine. (There are many other useful extensions, the ppa is well supported & responsive to any issues, none currently

ppa page - https://launchpad.net/~nae-team/+archive/ppa

To add ppa & install the Open Terminal Here extension

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nae-team/ppa
```

Then

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install nautilus-open-terminal-here
```

Answer (score 1):

Steps:

1. Download this [script file](http://www.mediafire.com/?hv7i3qd812sh6qk).
2. Right click in nautilus or on `Desktop → Scripts → Scripts` folder and extract the downloaded file into this folder.
3. Close the folder. That's it.

Comment: What's in the script file(s)? Wouldn't pasting it here be better than a .7z download?