# Embedded terminal in Nautilus?

Tags: command-line, nautilus

In Kubuntu, Dolphin File Manager has a cool feature that includes a terminal in it which can be toggled at any time by pressing <kbd>F4</kbd>. It also changes directories based on the user's navigation in the file browser.

Is there a similar feature for nautilus on Ubuntu?

**Note**:
I am not taking about `ubuntu-open-terminal`. That will just open a terminal at the current location; I'm looking for a terminal which will follow nautilus navigation.

Comment: Actually, in KDE Dolphin embeds Konsole. This is why if you install Dolphin under Unity (which works quite well but needs some tweaking for the looks), you also need to install konsole in order to have this functionality.

Comment: Related http://askubuntu.com/questions/121903/open-terminal-in-nautilus

Comment: @cst1992 , I know , I just added here as a comment for future reference :-)

Comment: @Tachyons That's okay then.

Comment: The version in the accepted answer is now outdated. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The version of Nautilus Terminal in [Parto's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/753590/176654) is now (as 2021-12-03) outdated.

The new version can be found on GitHub:

[github.com/flozz/nautilus-terminal](https://github.com/flozz/nautilus-terminal)

Comment: Changed accepted answer to this one 'cause the old one is outdated.

Answer (score 19):

That is [Nautilus Terminal](http://projects.flogisoft.com/nautilus-terminal/).

Nautilus Terminal is a terminal embedded in Nautilus, the GNOME's file browser. It is always open in the current folder, and follows the navigation (the `cd` command is automatically executed when you move to an other folder).

Nautilus Terminal has a lot of functionalities:

1. It always follows your navigation in your folders.
2. It supports Copy/Paste (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>).
3. It supports drag & drop of files and folders.
4. It can be hidden/shown when you want (with the <kbd>F4</kbd> key).
5. It is resize-able.

#### Installation

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:flozz/flozz
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nautilus-terminal
```

Then run this command to restart nautilus:

```
nautilus -q
```

[image]

Website: http://projects.flogisoft.com/nautilus-terminal/

Comment: Seriously, never heard of the existence of it. Nice catch!

Comment: @JacobVlijm Maybe you can come up with something like that. This one was last updated in 2011 (though still works with 14.04)

Comment: My option would not be as clean as this one :). Breaking into existing applications is not one of my skills yet :)

Comment: Oh, okay. Cool though, nice extension.

Comment: Excellent. Just what I was looking for.

Comment: @cst1992 Cool. Remember to upvote the answer too ;)

Comment: What other integration is there between the terminal and the GUI file manager? Just read about the auto `cd`, but does it do anything else neat?

Comment: @Xen2050 Yah, if you change directories on GUI it automatically changes in the terminal.

Comment: **@JacobVlijm, Parto** if it ever breaks, there is always [Nemo without Cinnamon extensions](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/install-nemo-with-unity-patches-and.html)

Comment: The Nautilus Terminal version in this answer is now outdated and no more developed, I have to update the site.... There is a new version on Github that works with latest Nautilus Version → https://github.com/flozz/nautilus-terminal